# for htc desire s: how to know your phone's region?

Tags: updates, htc-desire-s, localization

i'd like to update my software from gingerbread to ICS, just want to make sure to get the right update for my phone.

Answer (score 1):

You must have been confused by seeing too many files for the update. Actually there is only one file to update to ICS and hence it is the right file. The file is RUU, i.e. ROM Update Utility.

So from, http://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/downloads

Download

> Desire S  HTC  WWE  RUU  N/A  v4.0  404.0 MB  14.01.401.2

And yes the region is WWE for this case.

Comment: WWE being "WorldWidE" apparently.

Comment: @Broam - in HTCese, WWE means "WorldWide English".  It indicates that English is the base language, and that all other languages included are translated from the English, rather than being written directly in that language and that it's intended as a generic update for all carriers.  Some phones also offer an ARA RUU, which is much the same as WWE, except that the base language is Arabic.